# Concatenation formula based on criteria

Tags: excel, concatenation, criteria

I am having trouble with my concat,

I have a list of models concatenated in Cell E, however ideally I need all models with the same reference (Cell D) to have a concatenation of all unique models.

Apologies if not clear I'm 4 coffee's deep

[image: Example]

Comment: Share what your desired results would be as it's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. I'm betting some VBA will be required here (in the form of a UDF). Can you mock up what your sheet would look like if it were doing what you like and provide a screenshot of that as well?

Comment: apologies I thought I did in the very last column 'Desired result'

Comment: You sure did. Sorry I overlooked that. "All unique models" would be any distinct model number found in F:Q?

Comment: there wont be any distinct models,